# Is there any way to await on a lazy Deferred without starting its execution?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a lazy Deferred defined like this

```
val foo = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
    delay(100)
}
```

From the docs on [async](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html), calling .await() on foo will start its execution implicitly. I would like to await on foo() without starting execution. Is this possible?

Comment: I believe you can make this happen with `invokeOnCompletion`, which sets up a listener without (IIRC) triggering the coroutine to start, but it's certainly more work to make happen.

Comment: Could you elaborate? invokeOnCompletion does not suspend like await.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build something for this using `invokeOnCompletion`, though it takes some work.

```
suspend fun <T> Deferred<T>.awaitWithoutStartingLazy(): T {
  val completion = Job()
  invokeOnCompletion {
    completion.complete()
  }
  completion.join()
  return await() // the job is complete, so this doesn't suspend
}
```